# Plot problem with tikz and data from matlab

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, matlab

I extracted data from matlab figures, with the command
"dlmwrite('heat.txt',[x',u],'delimiter', '\t')". 
It gives me a text file with 3 columns of numbers (the first is the abscisse x, and the other are 2 functions f(x) and g(x)).
I wanted to plot it in Latex, so i've written this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {heat.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It's not working, I have the error : ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `heat' (in 'heat.txt').. 
Then, I put **file[skip first]** in the line \addplot and it's working, I have the graph of (x,f(x)). 
I don't understand because my text file is only number.
More important, I wanted to plot also (x,g(x)). So i've written:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot file[skip first] table[x index=0,y index=2] {heat.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And it does not work, the error is : ! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{t} could not be opened.
I tried it without "file[skip first]", and it's the same error.

I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot coordinates from a file use

```
\addplot table [<column selection>]{<file name>};
```

If the optional argument for `table` is missing, the first column (with index `0`) is used as `x` values and the second column (with index `1`) is used as `y`-values.

To plot `f(x)` with your file

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {heat.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

should work.

To plot the third column you can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {heat.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

From the manual:

> If you have data files, you should generally use `\addplot table`. The input
>   type `\addplot file` is almost the same, but considerably less powerful. It is only kept for backwards compatibility.